# Spring Boot Validation : how to test DTO object

Tags: spring-boot, validation, junit

I have the method in `StudentController` which I have to test. I want to test `StudentDTO` validation :

```
@PostMapping("successStudentAddition")
public String addStudent(@ModelAttribute("student") @Validated StudentDTO studentDTO, Errors errors, Model model) {

    if (errors.hasErrors()) {
        model.addAttribute(STUDENT_MODEL, studentDTO);
        return "/studentViews/addStudent";
    }

    Student student = new Student(studentDTO.getStudentId(), studentDTO.getStudentName(), studentDTO.getStudentSurname(),
            studentDTO.getStudentAge(), studentDTO.getEntryYear(), studentDTO.getGraduateYear(), studentDTO.getFacultyName(),
            groupService.getGroupIdByName(studentDTO.getGroupName()));
    studentService.addStudent(student);
    return "/studentViews/successStudentAddition";
}
```

`StudentDTO.class` :

```
public class StudentDTO {
@Id
private int studentId;
@NotNull
@Size(min=2,max=30,message = "Name should consist of 2 to 30 symbols!")
private String studentName;
@NotNull
@Size(min = 2, max = 30,message = "Surname should consist of 2 to 30 symbols!")
private String studentSurname;
@NotNull
@Min(value = 10,message = "Student age should be more than 10!")
private int studentAge;
@NotNull
@Min(value = 1900,message = "Entry year should be more than 1900!")
@Max(value=2021,message = "Entry year should be less than 2021!")
private int entryYear;
@NotNull
@Min(value = 2020,message = "Graduate year should be not less than 2020!")
private int graduateYear;
@NotNull
@Size(min = 3,message = "Faculty name should consist of minimum 3 symbols!")
private String facultyName;
@NotNull
@Size(min = 4,message = "Group name should consist of 4 symbols!")
@Size(max = 4)
private String groupName;
}
```

I found some idea for testing :

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest
class ValidatingServiceWithGroupsTest {
  @Autowired
private ValidatingServiceWithGroups service;
@Test
void whenInputIsInvalidForCreate_thenThrowsException() {
InputWithGroups input = validInput();
input.setId(42L);

assertThrows(ConstraintViolationException.class, () -> {
  service.validateForCreate(input);
});
}
@Test
void whenInputIsInvalidForUpdate_thenThrowsException() {
InputWithGroups input = validInput();
input.setId(null);

assertThrows(ConstraintViolationException.class, () -> {
  service.validateForUpdate(input);
});
}
}
```

But. If in the code above we testing service without any input parameters, I should to the controller with such parameteres : `Errors errors` and `Model model`.
And I have troubles with it.

All stacktrace after adding test :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'studentController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'studentService'; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.foxminded.springboot.service.StudentService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire 
candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.foxminded.springboot.service.StudentService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as 
autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

Answer (score 0):

From what you have provided in your question, I understand that you  need to test the validations on your `StudentDTO`  dto class. The validation on your dto class will be triggered at the time of binding automatically by spring. So, to test this validation all you have to do is call the controller method properly with the json that will trigger the validation and check the response .If the validation fails, it will trigger a `MethodArgumentNotValidException`. By default, Spring will translate this exception to a HTTP status 400 (Bad Request).

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@WebMvcTest(controllers = StudentController.class)
class StudentControllerTest {

  @Autowired
  private MockMvc mvc;

  @Autowired
  private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

  @MockBean
  private StudentService service;

  @Test
  void whenInputIsInvalid_thenReturnsStatus400() throws Exception {
    Input input = invalidInput();
    String body = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(input);

    mvc.perform(post("/successStudentAddition")
            .content(body))
            .andExpect(status().isBadRequest());
  }
}
```

But in your case , you are returning a different view when an error occurs , so you will need to test for that. So, in your case test the response like :

```
this.mockMvc.perform(post("/successStudentAddition")
.accept(MediaType.TEXT_HTML))
.andExpect(status().isOk())
.andExpect(model().attribute("yourmodel", "assertIt"))
.andDo(print());
```

Comment: I use Spring Boot and I think annotation `WebMvcTest` is not correct here because I catch an error `Failed to load application context`

Comment: @Jack `WebMvcTest` is a springboot annotation to test the web layer only. Read https://spring.io/guides/gs/testing-web/ . Why is it failing to load ? Could you share the stacktrace.

Comment: @Jack You could also use `AutoConfigureMockMvc` if you do not want to start the server but only application context.

Comment: I added the stacktrace to the post

Comment: @Jack Use 'MockBean' annotation to create  a mock service bean . I have updated the answer. Make sure you mock the service endpoints also. Please read the link i provided in previous comment. It has an example.

Comment: After this changing, I get 404 bad request now, not 400 expectable.
I added changes to the post, but I should to wait for approving it by other community members.